# Unlock Netsuite Records for Administrators

Tags: etl, netsuite, suitescript

I'm using an ETL pipeline to read Transaction data from Netsuite into my data warehouse.  I get the following message when I try to load the data:

```
RCRD_LOCKED_BY_WF: This record has been locked by a user defined workflow.
```

I do have an active workflow that locks some Transaction records.  My question is: is there a way to allow certain users (in my case, an administrative user) to read locked Netsuite records via the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a Condition on the Lock Record Action so that it does not run when Administrators (and any other Roles you wish) interact with the record. Or change the Context in which the Lock Record Action runs so that it only runs in the User Interface, for instance.

Comment: What's the mechanism for doing this?  Can I do this directly in the workflow, or do I have to write a SuiteScript for this?

Comment: Lock Record is an Action in the Workflow, and Actions have a Condition field that determines when they fire. See the Help article titled `Working with Conditions` for details.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh - i have the same scenario, done with the condition on the lock record action to not lock the record for an administrator. i m executing my script as administrator as well but still i face the same issue. any idea why?